# Injective objects in the category of $G$-modules

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, homological-algebra

I am reading about Hilbert's Theorem 90 in James Milne's [excellent notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) about Galois theory. The author introduced the notion of a $G$-module, which is just an abelian group together with a group homomorphism $G\to \text{Aut}(M)$. The author himself didn't mention the category of $G$-modules explicitly, but there is only one "reasonable" way for defining the morphisms. That is, homophisms of abelian groups $M\to N$ which are compatible with the actions of $G$ on $M$ and $N$.

Later he defined $H^1(G,M)$ where $M$ is a $G$-modules, and claimed that there is an exact sequence
$$0\to M'^G \to M^G\to M''^G\to H^1(G,M')\to H^1(G,M)\to H^1(G,M'')$$
So equivalently, we can define $H^1(G,M)$ as the first derived functor of
$$\begin{aligned}
\square^G: G-Mod &\to \mathbf{Ab}\\
           M &\to M^G
\end{aligned}$$
where $G-Mod$ is what I denote for the category of $G$-modules and $\mathbf{Ab}$ is the category of abelian groups. The question is, what are the injective objects in $G-Mod$ then? Also, I 'd like to know if there are some standard reference discussing these topics.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, $G$-modules as defined here are the same as modules over the integral group algebra $\mathbb{Z}G$, so the injective objects can be found the same way you usually would in a module category.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I haven't think that way earlier! Now that totally makes sense, since morphisms of $G$-modules is nothing other than morphisms of $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules